# InvalidArgumentError: required broadcastable shapes [Op:Add] tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am a using CLIP model. Where I have two models. One model output is `(20, 128, 256)` and the other one output is `(20, 256)`.

```
image_model_output = (20, 256)
text_model_output = (20, 128, 256)
```

I use the following to calculate this

```
logits = (tf.matmul(caption_embeddings, image_embeddings, transpose_b=True))
so it will be like `(20, 256) * (256, 128, 20)`
it's ouput will be `(20, 128, 20)`
```

Similarly I calculate like this

```
images_similarity = tf.matmul(
        image_embeddings, image_embeddings, transpose_b=True
    )
(Output)--> (20, 256) * (256, 20) = (20,20)
```

and this

```
captions_similarity = tf.matmul(
        caption_embeddings, caption_embeddings, transpose_b=True
    )
(Output)--> (20, 128, 256) * (256, 128, 20) = (20, 128, 128)
```

The problem arises here

```
targets = keras.activations.softmax(
        (captions_similarity + images_similarity) / (2 * self.temperature)
    )
```

So do I need to change the activation function or there is any way to add these 3d matrices with different shapes?
Sorry to technically explain like this but people with solid deep learning and machine learning backgorund will understand.

### NOTE: After adding `axis 1` like this `tf.expand_dims(image_embeddings, axis=1)` the below part runs successfully

```
targets = keras.activations.softmax(
    (captions_similarity + images_similarity) / (2 * self.temperature)
)
```

However after this there is a loss funtion like below

```
captions_loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(
        y_true=targets, y_pred=logits, from_logits=True
    )
```

which generates this error

```
ValueError: Shapes (2, 128, 128) and (2, 128, 1) are incompatible
```

Is it possible to solve this error?

Comment: you can add a dimension to `images_similarity` to make the shape `(20, 1, 256)`. with `tf.expand_dims(images_similarity, axis=1)` then try `captions_similarity + images_similarity`

Comment: This seems to be a very good idea. After adding I have a little problem with loss funtion. this is loss funtion `captions_loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(
            y_true=targets, y_pred=logits, from_logits=True
        )` Here we have logits shape is `2, 128, 1` and targets shape is `2, 128, 128`. And now it says `ValueError: Shapes (2, 128, 128) and (2, 128, 1) are incompatible`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the above error I used a different loss funtion. I changed the code like below.

```
captions_loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(
    y_true=targets, y_pred=logits, from_logits=True
)
```

To

```
captions_loss = keras.losses.kl_divergence(
    y_true=targets, y_pred=logits
)
```

To save time of developers I have answered to my own. I am available to discuss on it further if someone is interested.